# Experiencing Inconsistent Scroll Offset Values in React Three.js Application When Using useScroll()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am working on a React Three.js and Theatre.js application where I've integrated the useScroll hook from @react-three/drei to capture scroll information. However, I'm encountering an issue where the scroll offset values are inconsistent, especially when scrolling down. Despite expecting positive values, I notice that the offset occasionally starts with 0 but becomes negative as I scroll down.

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the scroll offset values to be consistently positive as I scroll down, reflecting the distance scrolled from the top of the page.

**Observed Behavior:**

Upon initial rendering, the offset is 0 as expected, since the scroll is on top of the page. However, when I start scrolling down, the offset becomes sometimes negative and sometimes positive where it needs to be consistently positive.

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/youngjunwoo92/apple_watch/draft/elastic-breeze?workspaceId=0847580b-e0f3-46ca-a524-3812bc39e3a5&embed=1&file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0006356ka8uh3ovc%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0002356k0p4kqheh%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0004356k5d8xlf08%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0005356k93ygtxdc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpuzk4iq0002356k0p4kqheh%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0002356k0p4kqheh%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clpuzk4iq0005356k93ygtxdc%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0005356k93ygtxdc%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpuzmtjg011a356ke32j8k57%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzmtjg011a356ke32j8k57%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clpuzk4iq0004356k5d8xlf08%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0004356k5d8xlf08%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4iq0003356kv3g60dj5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4lq001ddrfpbckvbinx%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzk4wt005v356kl8oyz0vw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522CSB_RUN_OUTSIDE_CONTAINER%253D1%2520devcontainer%2520templates%2520apply%2520--template-id%2520%255C%2522ghcr.io%252Fdevcontainers%252Ftemplates%252Fjavascript-node%255C%2522%2520--template-args%2520%27%257B%257D%27%2520--features%2520%27%255B%255D%27%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuzl2hx00hi356kbn5eqbks%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpuzl2hx00hi356kbn5eqbks%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

**Code Snippets:**

```
// App.jsx
import { Scroll, ScrollControls, useScroll } from '@react-three/drei';
// ... (other imports)

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className="h-full w-full overflow-hidden pt-[44px]">
        <Canvas gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}>
          <ScrollControls pages={5} damping={0.1}>
            // each component takes up 100 vh.
            <Hero />
            <About />
            <Feature />
            <Faq />
            <Contact />
          </ScrollControls>
        </Canvas>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

// Scene.jsx
import { useScroll } from '@react-three/drei';
// ... (other imports)

export default function Scene() {
  const scroll = useScroll();
  // ... (other code)

  useFrame(() => {
    if (scroll) {
      // This gives a negative number.
      const offset = scroll.offset;
      console.log('Scene Component Scroll Offset:', offset);
      // ... (rest of the code)
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... (other components) */}
    </>
  );
```